# dragging text along with cursor while mouse is clicked angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-template

is it possible dragging a text along with cursor while mouse is clicked on angular2? I'm designing a web "painter" app and want to be able to click on a textbox and drag it around the page as long as the mouse is still pressed, like you could do in any simple editing app.

snippets of code or links to websites that have examples would be helpful as I'm a visual learner! Assume I know my way around angular 2 (which I like to believe I do, to an extent)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need angular for this you can do it simply in HTML5 with the 'draggable' property:

```
<div draggable>My draggable text</div>
```